# Rewriterule redirects to URL and shows different URL?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a website hosted on an Apache server which hosts other domains. Therefore, I can't access the Apache configuration.

On our website, I've several domains. For one of them (domain `example.com`), I've created a subfolder (`mysub`), and created a subdomain (`ww2`) to end in this subfolder. I can't use `www` as I don't have access to the Apache config and therefore, I can't change the `DocumentRoot` folder.

I've created a rewriteurl to move all requests going to the domain (`example.com`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/ww2\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

This works well. Question, is it possible to cheat and display `www` in the browser instead of `ww2`?

I guess not and I couldn't find anything related on Google.
I know that best workaround would be to have a dedicated website but for now, I can't do it.
If a guru has a thought or a better idea as workaround, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is it possible to cheat and display in the browser url www instead of ww2?

No, you can't "fake" the URL (ie. hostname) in that way.

However, you don't necessarily need to and you don't necessarily need access to the server config to change the document root either. Instead, you could *internally rewrite* the request for the `www.example.com` host (ie. the `www` subdomain) to the `mysub` (or even `www`) subdirectory. The `ww2` subdomain is not required.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^mysub/ /mysub%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/ww2\.myadditionaldomain\.net\/" [R=301,L]
> ```

Incidentally, this would only "redirect" requests for the root. It wouldn't redirect `/foo` for instance.

(Also, no need to backslash escape slashes, colons and dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. This is not a regex. But even if it was a regex, slashes and colons carry no special meaning in Apache PCRE regex. This is very cPanel-esque.)